# No module "configparser" even upon installing configparser

Tags: python, configparser, python-packaging

I installed python module `configparser` with `pip install configparser` and it installed 3.5.0. Now, when I am using `import configparser` in my `.py` file, but then I am getting `No module named configparser`. Can someone explain why is this so and how can I fix it? I have `/usr/local/lib` in my `$PATH` where `configparser.py` is?

Comment: Python can't find the module. import is looking at $PYTHONPATH, not $PATH.

Comment: Oh, so i should export PYTHONPATH to /usr/local/lib, is that correct?

Comment: I exported PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib, but still the program is unable to find the module

Comment: I got it, i had to set the PYTHONPATH to absolute path like /usr/local/lib/python-2.7/dist-libraries. And it worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
from backports import configparser
```